# How is "il faut se farcir" translated in a context of sarcasm?

Tags: traduction, usage

A French friend sent an email with a political comment about M. Zemmour in the French elections. She writes from Paris:

"En plus des horreurs d'Ukraine ici il faut écouter (je dirais plutôt **il faut "se farcir ")** les discours de Zemmour=Trump N°2. avec la crainte, la terreur, que comme Trump, il finisse par être élu.
(je ne sais pas traduire **"il faut se farcir"** en Anglais/ we have to swallow is not strong enough )"

I know that "se farcir" can indicate "stuffing oneself with food" in a different context. Here, would one say something like, "...we have to swallow his discourse" or "...we are choking on his discourse"? I beg your pardon if you are a Zemmour supporter, but my question is about language not politics. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I fear you will be told that into-English translation is not something this site does.  So, just to help you quickly before that happens:  [...] we have to listen to Zemmour's speeches (or rather, we're force fed them or they're stuffed down our throats. That's how I would translate farcir here. One has to come up with a credible sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/farcir)) **B.** − Emploi pronom.
> **2.** À valeur réfl. [Suivi d'un compl. d'obj.; le pron. a une valeur de compl. d'obj. indir.]
> **a)** **Fam.** Se farcir (la panse, le chou...). Se remplir, se saturer (de), manger avec excès. Ah! quel plaisir de boire frais, De se farcir la panse! (Berlioz, Grotesques mus.,1859, p. 29).Cf. aussi Martin du G., Gonfle, 1928, III, 2, p. 1228.
> **b) Au fig**. Se farcir (la tête, la cervelle) de. Surcharger son esprit, son intelligence, de notions, de connaissances pas toujours utiles. Laissez-là tous vos déclamateurs de tribunes et toutes ces billevesées grecques et latines dont vous vous êtes farci la mémoire (Jouy, Hermite,t. 1, 1811, p. 97).

The meaning of this verb in your sentence is close to "**B 2. b)**", but the precise meaning is another one, which is found in another dictionary.

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/se_farcir))  **se farcir** \sə faʁ.siʁ\ pronominal 2e groupe
> Forme pronominale de farcir.

This entry explains the meaning through a synonym, "*se coltiner*" ; out of the two options the second is the right one.

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/se_coltiner#fr)) **se coltiner**
>
> (Figuré) (Familier) Se charger d’une tâche fatigante, **supporter quelqu’un ou quelque chose**.
> ♦    On en a déjà bavé pour apprendre le solfège, et il faut encore se coltiner un langage de programmation pour pouvoir l’écrire ! — (forum.framasoft.org, 2006)
> ♦ J’en avais ras le bol de me coltiner la vaisselle tous les jours et d’avoir toujours l’évier rempli de vaisselle sale en rentrant du boulot.

Notice that this is colloquial French. A translation that is not colloquial in English but that is faithfull is obtained with the phrasal verb "to sit through".

- … you have *to sit through* Zemmour's speeches

Answer (score 2):

That reflexive *se farcir* is simply some colloquial way of expressing something is a *chore*, something you have to *suffer through* ("Exécuter de mauvaise grâce un travail ennuyeux ou pénible", [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/farcir)) or that someone is hard to bear ("Supporter avec beaucoup de mal", [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/farcir)); it's similar to *se taper* ("Faire; être obligé, contraint de faire", [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/taper)). Translation to English is not on topic, it's a matter of choice and context, register and style etc. and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/farcir#French) suggests things like "to get saddled with; to have to put up with", you can add ideas like *having to take something* ([Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/farcir/32798)), similar to *se taper* which could be something like *be stuck with* ([Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/taper/75757)). No need to go culinary/anatomical on this, just select something pretty informal and natural in context for you to express those ideas.

---

*Sources*

[TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/farcir) (j'identifie B. 3. a, b comme correspondant à l'exemple en question) :

**B.−** *Emploi pronom*.
**1.** *À valeur passive*. *Les dindons se farcissent avec des truffes* (Littré).
**2.** *À valeur réfl.* [Suivi d'un compl. d'obj.; le pron. a une valeur de compl. d'obj. indir.]
**a)** *Fam. Se farcir (la panse, le chou...)*. Se remplir, se saturer (de), manger avec excès. *Ah! quel plaisir de boire frais, De se farcir la panse!* (Berlioz, *Grotesques mus.*,1859, p. 29).Cf. aussi Martin du G., *Gonfle*, 1928, III, 2, p. 1228.
**b)** *Au fig. Se farcir (la tête, la cervelle) de*. Surcharger son esprit, son intelligence, de notions, de connaissances pas toujours utiles. *Laissez-là tous vos déclamateurs de tribunes et toutes ces billevesées grecques et latines dont vous vous êtes farci la mémoire* (Jouy, *Hermite*, t. 1, 1811, p. 97).
**3.** *Argot*
**a)** [Le compl. désigne un inanimé concr. ou abstr.]
− *Se farcir (un travail, une tâche)*. Exécuter de mauvaise grâce un travail ennuyeux ou pénible. Synon. se taper, se coltiner. *Je me le suis farci [le piano à déménager] tout seul* (Trignol, *Pantruche*, 1946, p. 87).
**♦** *Rare*. S'offrir, s'acheter quelque chose. *Tu te rends compte de ce qu'on peut se farcir avec quinze mille francs!* (Vialar, *Faux-fuyants*, 1953, p. 120).
− *Se farcir une peine (de prison)*. La purger. *Tu sors du ballon? Combien que tu t'es farci? − Dix piges* (Trignol, *Pantruche*, 1946 p. 91).
**b)** [Le compl. désigne une pers.]
− Supporter avec beaucoup de mal. *Jojo était avare (...) mais, en plus, fallait se le farcir!* (Simonin, *Pt Simonin ill.*,1957, p. 190).
− *Trivial. Se farcir une femme*. Coucher avec elle. Synon. se taper, s'envoyer. *On aurait voulu le poirer nous en train de se farcir la patronne* (Céline, *Mort à crédit*, 1936, p. 201).

---

[Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/farcir/32881#32800) :

Populaire

1. Assurer l'exécution de quelque chose malgré la difficulté, l'ennui, le déplaisir, etc. ; s'envoyer : Je me suis farci tout le travail.

Synonymes :

s'appuyer (populaire) - se coltiner (populaire) - se taper (populaire) - s'envoyer (populaire)

---

[Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/farcir#fr) :
[...]

3. *(Pronominal) (Familier)* Faire quelque chose sans grand plaisir, supporter quelqu'un ou quelque chose de déplaisant.

   *Mais je dois rester, chéri. Hein, dans ce bled ? mais t'es folle ! tu voulais Vegas pas Triffouilly-les-Oies ! Ce contrat tu m'as dit toi-même que c'était juste pour rendre service à ton agent ou à je ne sais plus qui, et que ça te faisait drôlement braire de **te farcir** cette trotte.* — (Joseph Bialot & al., *Du noir dans le vert : nouvelles*, éd. Ecailler du sud, 2002, vol. 1, page 129)

---

[Robert en ligne](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/farcir) :
[...]
3. familier *Se farcir (qqch.)* : avoir, consommer.
— Faire (une corvée). *Se farcir tout le travail.*
— Supporter. *Celui-là, il faut se le farcir !*

---

[Wordreference](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/se%20farcir) : Se farcir [qch]. familier. Faire sans plaisir. Se farcir [qqn]. familier. Supporter.

---

[L'internaute.fr](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/se-farcir/) : Endurer, supporter quelqu'un ou quelque chose.

---

[Usito](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/farcir#contenu_macro_sens-111-6) :
[...]
2 Faire avec contrariété.
Se farcir les corvées.
« *il parcourt le monde, visite les experts, se farcit tous les bouquins sur la question et s'empresse de faire connaître son expertise à ses clients* » (*Commerce*, 1994). 
3 péj. Subir, supporter.
⇒  endurer.
*Se farcir un vendeur insistant.*